# Improve import speed of data into MySQL DBs (large data)

Tags: mysql

I am having a pretty large data collection here with scripts for importing into a mysql database. The data are about 40GB and it takes ages to import the resources that are taken during importing are much less that mysql could take. The CPU is at most at 50%.

I googled a bit wondering how to make that quicker and google said LOAD DATA INFILE is pretty much the fastest way unfortunately my scripts are already using it

```
mysql -u$USR -p$PW $3 -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '`pwd`/data' INTO TABLE mydata;";
```

The last time I let the import run interactively on the command prompt and not in the background. I was wondering fi that has influence on the actual speed for this kind of things?

Does anyone has other ideas or advices how to make an import faster. I would at least except that mysql would greedily take all my CPU time, but it doesnt. I can let my import run over 2 days and it should be finished (I actually tried 1 day and it yet wasnt finished....~30GB had to move my computer and aboard the import), but I would appreciate a solution that makes full use of the resources I have in my computer

Comment: Which engine are your importing tables?

Comment: Run full system profiling, is your CPU the bottleneck or the HDD?

Comment: 40GB of data is going to take a while, unless you upgrade to an SSD. But it shouldn't take 2 days for sure. Can you split your file into smaller chunks and try each in sequence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/ that pretty much sums it up!

Comment: This answer is just a link. Links die. Please copy/paste the important parts of the article here.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer although you're correct, the article is pretty long and simply copy-pasting it wouldn't do justice to the lengthy arguments made therein. To somewhat alleviate your issue i've archived it into the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20210621131832/https://kvz.io/improve-mysql-insert-performance.html